# NavigationView.setItemTextAppearance() not working

Tags: android, android-navigationview, textstyle

I built a `NavigationView` using Java code and then I set the text style to keep the text of my menu items in a specific color and font using the method `setItemTextAppearance(int resId)`. But this method is not working. My text is not changing.

**Note** : All the other methods are working great, like `setItemTextColor()`, `setItemBackground()` etc.

Here is my code:

```
mNavigationView = new NavigationView(context);

mNavigationView.setId(R.id.nav_view);
mNavigationView.setFitsSystemWindows(true);

// This method works great!  
mNavigationView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));

// This too. 
mNavigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context,  android.R.color.white)));

// This method is not working.   
mNavigationView.setItemTextAppearance(R.style.MenuTextStyle);
```

Here is my style code:

```
 <style name="MenuTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">0sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose making your `style` a descendant of the default `style` that is applied to `NavigationView`'s items would work out:

```
<style name="MenuTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

In Java code:

```
    navigationView.setItemTextColor(null);
    navigationView.setItemTextAppearance(R.style.MenuTextStyle);
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra, this setup works in my machine.

Comment: try to apply a color inside the style and remove 
    `navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context,  android.R.color.holo_blue_bright)));`  from your java code

Comment: `setItemTextColor()` [has a higher priority](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L422) than the color specified in the style.

Comment: Yes, I but if I remove it, the color inside the style is not applied.

Comment: Because `mTextColor` is not null. By default [it has some color applied](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.java#L143) from default `NavigationView` style.

Comment: But I define a new color inside my style and I apply it into my `NavigationView` using `setItemTextAppearance`. So it should work, It looks like a bug.

Comment: It won't, because `NavigationView` will apply it's default color specified in it's style. If you want to use the color specified on your custom style, you have to null out that default value performing `navigationView.setItemTextColor(null);`. Then the color from your style would be applied.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @azizbekin, it still seems like a bug to me hahaha , but I understand your point. Anyway now I know how to proceed. Thanks a lot!